# How to fb hide the emoticons path and how to find it

Tags: php, facebook, chat, emoticons

I normaly make an

```
array(

" :) ", " :( "

);
```

with the emoticons then i make another array with the replacement

```
array(

'<img src="smile.png"/>',
'<img src="sad.png"/>'
);
```

then I use `str_replace ($theFirstArray, $secondArray, $and here is the message);`

But i notes that in fb chat the emoticons dont have paths to the image instead they lead to

https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/images/blank.gif

How is this is accomplished ?

Comment: I suppose they are assigned from a css sprite by using css.